# How to insert a new element at the front of a vector?

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector such as this; (1X2406)

```
head(lnreturn)
[1]           NA  0.004002188  0.003262646 -0.009454616  0.001460387
[6]  0.004005103
```

I would like to insert an NA as a first element so that I could reach a vector like this:

```
[1]           NA   NA           0.004002188  0.003262646 -0.009454616          
[6] 0.001460387
```

Hence, I would get a vector in (1X2407) dimension.

Comment: Maybe `lnreturn <- c(NA,lnreturn)` ?

Comment: I don't know how to manage this question. Maybe one suggestion: read the manual!

Comment: > lnreturn <- c(NA,lnreturn)
> head(lnreturn)
[1]           NA           NA  0.004002188  0.003262646 -0.009454616
[6]  0.001460387    ....It worked!

Comment: or typing `R concatenating two vectors` , `R adding element to vector` in your web browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its easy (like etienne posted)
if you want a vector with same length as a result (like in your example) you can use length().

```
x<-rnorm(10)
x<-c(NA,x)[1:length(x)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use `c()`

```
x<-rnorm(10)
x<-c(NA,x)

 x
 [1]           NA -0.004620768  0.760242168  0.038990913  0.735072142 -0.146472627
 [7] -0.057887335  0.482369466  0.992943637 -1.246395498 -0.033487525
```